# Android load multiple menu layout files possible?

Tags: android, layout, menu, subclass

I want to have a superclass activity that defines what basic menu items each activity should have in addition to their own.

Here is my code so far:

```
public abstract class SuperActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    protected List<TextView> textView = new ArrayList<TextView>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getContentResource());

        setTextViews(textView);

    }

    protected abstract void setTextViews(List<TextView> textViews);

    protected abstract int getContentResource();

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menuitemsforallsubclasses, menu);
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.basicmenuitem1:
            allSubclassActivitiesCanDoThis()
            return true;
        case R.id.basicmenuitem2:
            allSubclassActivitiesCanDoThis2()
            return true;

        }
    }
}
```

In the subclasses I would then just add something to onCreateOptionsMenu (an additional layout file) and onOptionsItemSelected, is that correct? Just want to make sure I am not on the wrong track here. Would it even be possible to load multiple layout file in the same activity?

FYI: In case you are wondering why I have a TextView array in the activity: In addition to this I want to have all TextViews of each subclass activity in an ArrayList, so that I can add listeners to all of them automatically so I know when something has changed in the activity or to do some other neat stuff.

Is what I am doing possible? Is it possible to load multiple menu layout files?